# This method is more easy to understand. This method is easier to understand

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

This method is more easy to understand. 
This method is easier to understand.

Which one is correct sentence and why?

Comment: I could not find answer to question.  Please share your views regarding my sentences.

Comment: I found it easily but still I am confused how can we use [more easy]?

Comment: Sumelic thanks to you.  Thanks to both of you. By the way,  More easy is correct or incorrect in my sentence?